# Rename file upload "choose file"

Tags: php, file

How can I change the default file Input button (choose file) to say instead "Add Photo", and also hide "no file chosen"?
Here's the code I currently have in the plugin:

```
echo '<p style="clear: both"><input style="width: 100%;max-width: 240px;" type="file" name="image' . ($i==0?'':$i) . '"/> ' . htmlspecialchars($options['label']) . '</p>';
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this with CSS and the content property along with other properties to hide the default tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

```css
.button::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.button::before {
  content: 'Upload Image';
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4px 7px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.button:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}

.button:active::before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" class="button">
```

Use the `value` attribute:

```
<input value="Add Photo" style="width: 100%;max-width: 240px;" type="file" name="image' . ($i==0?'':$i) . '"/>
```

Comment: I tried using your code but nothing happens. I cleared the cache...